# grails - controlling access of asset resources

Tags: grails, spring-security, asset-pipeline

I want to have control who can and can not access a specific folder in the assets folder.

I actually want to look in the database if the user can access that folder.
I am using the grails spring security plugin.

In the config file I declared assets as a permitAll because there are also resources that should be public available. I looked into the filtering of the plugin but most that I found was a custom authentication filter. I don't want to touch the auth. I just want to do some check additionally / on top

**edit:**

I also tried normal grails filters- I put the file "AssetsFilter.groovy" in the conf folder. But they are never called:

```
class AssetsFilter {
    def filters = {
        allURIs(uri: '/**') {
            log.debug "aaa"
            println "aaa1"
            before = {
                log.debug "bbb"
                println "bbb1"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of grails are you using?

Comment: sorry. I am using 2.4.4.

Comment: Have you looked at [grails filters](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#filters)?

Comment: yes. but grails never intercepted. (I put a log.debug and println inside the before closure) Should I paste my code?

Comment: The convention calls for the file/class name to end with `Filters` (because it can contain multiple).  Use the grails `create-filters` target to be sure.

Comment: thank you. That was it... I acutally checked the Name ends with a 's' but must have tomato's on my eyes... You can do it as an answer and i will check it as correct